# vim/gvim remote editing

Tags: vim

I use vim/gvim to edit multiple files. This means I start an instance as server:

```
gvim --servername VIM
```

Then i have multiple calls to

```
vim -remote filename
```

This works great - until i want to close one of the buffers. If I try to do that the whole server closes, regardless of the command used: :q, :db

This happens with vim and gvim. It happens only if it is used as server.

Any ideas why this is happening? Solutions? Is it a Bug or just a feature I don't really get?

Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that behavior when I try it on vim 7.3. if you do a `:ls` in the vim you are running how many buffers does it show? I would probably also recommend specifying the server name when opening new files.

```
vim --servername VIM --remote-silent filename
```

That way if you have multiple gvims open you can make sure the files open in the right one.

Comment: Hm. today I can't even reproduce it myself...
Maybe a reboot helps...

Thanks anyway!